# calculate row wise total and grand total

Tags: jquery, html

for invoice application, i want to find row wise total and grand total, these rows are created using nested form. it is working for first row when i change the value of discount, but i want this for all rows.

this is my code.

```
 $(".hr").each(function() {
     row = $(this).parent("td").parent();
     total    = 0;
     qnt      = 0;
     rate     = 0;
     discount = 0;
     $(row).find("td input.hr")on("change",function(index) {
         if ($(this).val() !== "") {
            if ($(this).hasClass('quantity')){
                 qnt = parseFloat($(this).val());
            }
            if($(this).hasClass('rate')){
                rate = parseFloat($(this).val());
            }
            if($(this).hasClass('discount')){
                discount = parseFloat($(this).val());
            }
            return total = (qnt*rate)-(discount)
         }
     });
     $(row).find("td input.total").val(total);
     $('#invoice_grand_total').val(total)
 });

 <tr>
<td><%= f.text_field :item_name %></td>
<td><%= f.text_field :description %></td>
<td><%= f.text_field :quantity, :class => 'quantity hr' %></td>
<td><%= f.text_field :rate, :class => 'rate hr' %></td>
<td><%= f.text_field :discount, :class => 'discount hr' %></td>
<td>
    <td><%= f.text_field :total, :class => 'total', :disabled => true %></td>
 </tr>
```

Comment: You should provide more information you know, like at what point you are getting stuck, what did you do to solve it, etc. This is not a place where people are just waiting to test some random code doing something.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know when you are calling this `$(".hr").each(` code, but it won't update the `input.total` and `#invoice_grand_total` when your `.hr` elements change since the `val(total)` statements for those fields are outside the `on` function.
Instead of returning the total in the `on` function, set the values in there.